# Chrome Extension : Tab issues

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The code below attempts to open a new tab for the corresponding post object, when its image is  clicked in popup.html.  For some reason, the new tab is blank and isn't going to the right page as specified by this.Link in the Post singleton.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            min-width:357px;
            overflow-x:hidden;
        }

        img {
            margin:5px;
            border:2px solid black;
            vertical-align:middle;
            width:75px;
            height:75px;
        }
    </style>


    <script>
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open(
        "GET",
        "http://thekollection.com/feed/",
        true);
        req.onload = showPosts;
        req.send(null);

        function showPosts() {
            var elements = req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("item");

            for (var i = 0, item; item = elements[i]; i++) {
                var description = item.getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                var link = item.getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                var txtLink = link.toString();
                var txtDesc = description.toString();

                var start = txtDesc.indexOf("\"") + 1;
                var end = txtDesc.indexOf(".jpg") + 4;
                var imgURL = txtDesc.substring(start, end);

                var post = new function(){
                    this.Link = txtLink;
                    this.Description = txtDesc;
                    this.ImageURL = imgURL;
                    this.imgElement = document.createElement("image");
                    this.displayTab = function(){
                        chrome.tabs.create({'url' : this.Link}, function(tab){});
                    }
                }


                post.imgElement.addEventListener("click", post.displayTab, false)
                post.imgElement.src = post.ImageURL;

                document.body.appendChild(post.imgElement);
            }       
        }     
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You register `post.displayTab` as an event listener on `post.imgElement` which means that the value of `this` will be `post.imgElement` when the event listener is called. Consequently, there is no `Link` property (`this.Link` is undefined). One way to avoid this problem would be registering the event handler differently:

```js
post.imgElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
    post.displayTab();
}, false)
```

`post.displayTab` is called as a method of the `post` object here so `this` variable will be set correctly. The other option is to stop using `this` in `post.displayTab`:

```js
this.imgElement = document.createElement("image");
var me = this;
this.displayTab = function(){
    chrome.tabs.create({'url' : me.Link}, function(tab){});
}
```

The `me` variable remembers the "correct" `this` value.

Comment: @Jasdev: Feel free to accept the answer if it helped: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask